# Choosing random picturebox out of 20 of them c#

Tags: c#, winforms, random

I'm having a hard time with choosing a random `PictureBox`.

I want to choose 2 random `PictureBox` and set the same image for both of them. The function should repeat 5 times.

I've tried using an array, but I received an error that says that pictureBox1 can't be transformed into an array.

```
string[] array1 = new string[]
{
    pictureBox1,
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have an list of PictureBoxes. Like so:

```
var picList = new List<PictureBox>();
```

And you fill the list with PictureBox Controls.

```
picList.Add(pictureBox1)
picList.Add(pictureBox2)
picList.Add(pictureBox3)
//etc
```

And you want to pick at random, a picture box from the list.  You can just use the `Next` function of the `Random` class to generate you a number between 0 and the size of the list.

For example, first declare your random class at the class level scope:

```
static Random rnd = new Random();
```

Then, within your function, when you want to generate a random number use the `Next` function, like so.

```
randomNum = rnd.Next(0, picList.Count);
```

Once you have your number, you can set the image to whatever you want. Repeat that a 2nd time for the 2nd PictureBox.  For example:

```
var picBox = picList[randomNum];
picBox.Image = ?? // set image here!
```

Comment: Well I have the same error again `Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Drawing.Image'` 

And error is on line where is `picBox.Image`

Comment: try this: picBox.Image = Image.FromFile(@"c:\Images\a.jpg");

Comment: Thank you, really, everything is working now ! Many thanks for u guys!!